# Ipywidgets Jupyter Notebook Interact Ignore Argument

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

Is there a way to have `interact(f)` ignore certain arguments in `f`? I believe it is getting confused by the fact that I have a default argument that I use to pass in a dataframe. Here is my function:

```
def show_stats(start,end,df_pnl=df_pnl):
    mask = df_pnl['Fulldate'] >= start & df_pnl['FullDate'] <= end
    df_pnl = df_pnl[mask]
    #do some more transformations here
    display(df_pnl)
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
interact(show_stats,start=start_str,end=today_str)
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

[image]

I hypothesize that `interact` somehow changes `df_pnl` into a string (since it gives a dropdown of the column headers in the interact output), and fails because it then tries to do `df_pnl['Fulldate'].....` on a string, which causes the error shown.

How do I get around this? Could I exclude that argument from my function while still having it work on the correct dataframe? Is there an option within interact to ignore certain arguments in the function?

Thanks

Comment: Did you happen to try my solution?

Comment: If you're confused about to do when your question is answered this link has some [helpful tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I'd appreciate an upvote if you don't mind. I upvoted the question so it kinda just makes right? Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it is a little difficult to test this solution without a sample DataFrame but I think that [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) may be what you are looking for. Essentially `partial` allows you to define a new function with one of the keyword arguments or positional arguments loaded beforehand. Try the code below and see if works;

```py
from functools import partial

def show_stats(start, end, df_pnl):
    mask = df_pnl['Fulldate'] >= start & df_pnl['FullDate'] <= end
    df_pnl = df_pnl[mask]
    #do some more transformations here
    display(df_pnl)

# Define the new partial function with df_pnl loaded.
show_stats_plus_df = partial(show_stats, df_pnl=YOUR_DATAFRAME)

interact(show_stats_plus_df, start=start_str, end=today_str)
```

Update:

You could also try ipywidgets the [`fixed`](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Fixing-arguments-using-fixed) function.

```py
from ipywidgets import fixed

def show_stats(start, end, df_pnl):
    mask = df_pnl['Fulldate'] >= start & df_pnl['FullDate'] <= end
    df_pnl = df_pnl[mask]
    #do some more transformations here
    display(df_pnl)

interact(show_stats, start=start_str, end=today_str, df_pnl=fixed(df_pnl))
```

Please comment below if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm confused because this doesn't work for me:
```python
def g(dat, x):
    print("dat={dat} from inside g")
    return dat

from functools import partial, update_wrapper

def wrapped_partial(func, *args, **kwargs):
    partial_func = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
    update_wrapper(partial_func, func)
    return partial_func

g_plus_dat = wrapped_partial(g, dat='a')

interact(g_plus_dat, x=10)
```
gives
`ValueError: cannot find widget or abbreviation for argument: 'dat'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use closures:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact

def show_stats(start, end, df_pnl)
  @interact(start=start_str, end=today_str)
  def _show_stats(start, end):
      mask = df_pnl['Fulldate'] >= start & df_pnl['FullDate'] <= end
      df_pnl = df_pnl[mask]
      #do some more transformations here
      display(df_pnl)
```